# how to escape the character < while replacing a string using sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace the string `@STYLESHEET` present in a text file with `<xsl:stylesheet` using sed.

I am getting error saying

> The filename,directory name, or volumelabel syntax is incorrect

Below is my bat script:

```
       ECHO replacing strings in Generated.txt
       sed   s/@STYLESHEET/<xsl:stylesheet'/g Generated.txt > UpdatedGenerated.txt
       PAUSE
       type UpdatedGenerated.txt
```

The text file has the below line:

```
@STYLESHEET version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" @END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<` character is fine. However, you have an apostrophe at the end of replacement, not sure why. Moreover, you have to pass the sed command as a string: `sed '...'` or `sed "..."`. The required quote type depends on your console too.

So, this will make your script work well:

```
sed   "s/@STYLESHEET/<xsl:stylesheet/g" Generated.txt > UpdatedGenerated.txt
     ^^^                             ^^^
```

Comment: When i tried sed  's/@STYLESHEET/<xsl:stylesheet/g'  Generated.txt > UpdatedGenerated.txt  getting incorrect syntax.  when i try sed  's/@STYLESHEET/xsl:stylesheet/g'  Generated.txt > UpdatedGenerated.txt getting invalid command.  when i try without single quote and the character < then it works fine.

Comment: It might depend on your console too. You can try double quotes too.

Answer (score 1):

It worked after putting the options  in double quotes. The problem was not with the character <.
                    `sed "s/@STYLESHEET/<xsl:stylesheet/g" Generated.txt > UpdatedGenerated.txt`